# AppEngine Python Query with aggregate

Tags: python, google-app-engine, properties, aggregate

I have the following model:

```
class Conversation:
    questionId = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    count = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    message = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

A conversation consists of the original question id, the message count, and the message.  So an example of data would be:

```
- questionId: 2; count: 0; message: How are you?
- questionId: 2; count: 1; message: I'm fine thanks, how are your kids?
- questionId: 2; count: 2; message: They're great, growing to fast!
- questionId: 3; count: 0; message: John, your late!
- questionId: 3; count: 1; message: I know, I'm so sorry!
```

My question here is, how can I query to get the latest (biggest) count per each question id?  From the above example, it would return:

```
- questionId: 2; count: 2; message: They're great, growing to fast!
- questionId: 3; count: 1; message: I know, I'm so sorry!
```

Keep in mind that unfortunately the data is not stored sorted like in the example, so imagine the rows all out of order.  Also the table count is huge!  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Add a 'latest' flag to each record, which you set to true only for the most recent question with a given ID, and set to false when a new record replaces it.
- Use a separate query for each ID, fetching only the most recent question for each (using sort and `.get()`.

Which makes the most sense depends on how many unique questions you're retrieving at any given time. If it's more than a few, you should probably modify your model.

Answer (score 0):

```
question_id = 'whatever'
latest_convo = Conversation.gql('WHERE questionId = :1 ORDER BY count DESC', question_id).get()
```

Comment: That only works when I know the question id, right?  I'd be querying on all of them.

Comment: oh, apologies, i wasn't aware of that. nicks first answer sounds like the best one to me then